# simple-form grouped collection select for has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have three models as shown

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location_name
  has_many :areas
  has_many :restaurants, through: :areas
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area_name, :location_id
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :restaurants
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :description, :menu, :restaurant_name, :area_id
  belongs_to :area
end
```

Am using simple-form gem and i want create a new restaurant and select a Location first which has many areas and the correct areas associated with a location to be automatically selected. Then i narrow down to a single area. Similar in concept to say how someone would select Continents and then be narrowed down to a country in a particular continent. Is there a way to achieve this using simple_form.?
Do i have anything extra to the new action in the restaurant controller?

This is my view so far for creating a new restaurant

```
<%= simple_form_for @restaurant do |f| %>
<%= f.input :restaurant_name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :menu %>
<%= f.input :area_id,collection: @locations, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :areas%>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This doesnot work as expected. I have already populated my database with Locations and Areas. Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe how it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the options the other way around, `collection` is the parent group, not the child group. In your case you need:

```
<%= f.input :area_id,collection: @areas, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :locations %>
```

Comment: What I did above actually works. I just needed to add `@locations =location.all` in the restaurant `new` action. However it brought objects in the menu. so i added `label_method: :area_name` after `group_method` Now the area names can be seen but still see Object representation for the location. How do i get the `location_name`